# Do I need to delete the temporary table manually in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I know that the temporary table will be deleted at the end of the PostgreSQL session. But I'm wondering if there are obvious pros and cons to doing it manually?

I did not find a clear answer, can you share what you think about this?

Comment: Temp tables are overhead like any other object. That being said unless you are generating a large number of tables or tables with large amount of data in a given session I don't see a need to manage them manually. The definition of large being dependent on the resources available to the database. So what you can do on a new top of the line server is not the same as you can do on a Raspberry Pi.